# Visual Studio Online Build Fails on Dependent Project NuGet References

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online for my repo and build. Here is my TFS hierarchy.

```
            <ClassLibraries>
                │
                ├───<Solution 1>
                │   └───Build.Proj
                │   └───.NuGet
                │       └───NuGet.exe
                │       └───NuGet.Config
                │       └───NuGet.Targets
                │   └───<Project 1>                 // Common Code
                │       └───Project1.csproj
                │   └───<Project 2>                 // Common Code Unit Test
                │       └───Project2.csproj
                │
                ├───<Solution 2>
                │   └───Build.Proj
                │   └───.NuGet
                │       └───NuGet.exe
                │       └───NuGet.Config
                │       └───NuGet.Targets
                │   └───<Project 3>
                │       └───Project1.csproj
                │   └───<Project 4>
                │       └───Project2.csproj
```

I have a build definition for Solution 1 which builds succesfully, restoring the NuGet packages as required without issue.

The Solution 2.sln file includes Project 1 from Solution 1 as a dependency, as both Project 3 and Project 4 have code dependencies on it (Solution 1 is my common code solution, which is included in just about everything).

The build definition for Solution 2 fails because it cannot find the NuGet dependencies for Project 1. I guess the RestorePackages target in the Build.Proj is ignoring the dependent project.

```
              <Target Name="RestorePackages">
                <Exec Command="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).NuGet\NuGet.exe restore %(Solution.Identity)" />
              </Target>
```

I can't fathom out why. If I execute "msbuild build.proj" locally on Solution 2 then it cleans and builds all projects succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out that my build.proj file needs to reference directly Solution 1 in this example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*.sln" /> 
    <Solution Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Solution1\*.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This then causes MSBuild to go through the NuGet package restore for the dependent project.  Problem solved. Sort of..

After I had deleted all my local code and performed a Get Latest from the repo, I realised that VS2013 exhibits the behaviour I originally saw. So I need now to work out how to make the IDE build in the same way as the Build.Proj file I am using for VSO and msbuild executed from the command line.